Why are dots big and small in the PCA plot drawed with fviz_pca_ind()?
I use fviz_pca_ind() to draw a PCA plot, but the point size is different.
This is my code:
library(FactoMineR)
library(factoextra)
pca.res <- PCA(iris[, 1:3])
fviz_pca_ind(pca.res, 
             geom.ind='point', 
             col.ind=iris$Species, 
             addEllipses=TRUE, 
             palette='lancet')

And this is the result, as circled in the red box, the point is bigger than other.

So, why did this happen?
And, I checked the source code of fviz_pca_ind and found the point size controlled in the code like this:
if (nrow(df) != length(pointsize)) 
  pointsize <- 1.5
df[["pointsize"]] <- pointsize
pointsize <- "pointsize"

But this doesn't seem to be the reason for the different in point size.

The larger points are the means. If not desired you can drop them using mean.point = FALSE(see ?fviz).
